Unknown class from MUI
I am writing styles to the MUI`s component, and want to get rid of additional class, but idk how to do it. It is looking like this: "css-10jgzd0-MuiToolbar-root", I want to delete MuiToolbar-root
I tried applying ThemeProvider, but it doesnt help, or maybe Im doing it wrong

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
